# How to change the text color of items in a QListWidget?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I want to change the text color of the items in `QListWidget`.
For example, some items are in red text while others are in blue text. How do I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
QListWidget t;
t.addItem("first");
t.addItem("second");
t.item(0)->setForeground(Qt::red);
t.item(1)->setForeground(Qt::blue);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done by stylesheets. E.g.:

```
QListWidget::item {
    color:#00ff00;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Set it by [setStylesheet(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop)